# HTML include js files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I realize this question has been asked many times, however I don't manage to make it working

I have an html file (main.html) that is including two js files (etherjs.js and web3-min.js). These files are in the same directory.

But when requesting the page through localhost node server, the files are not included in the page

What I am doing wrong?

[image]

Error of the console (it is saying error loading the eleent which source is:):

[image]

Comment: Try putting a slash before the file name as you refer them: `<script src="/etherjs.js">` Also, check the browser console to see what the errors are.

Comment: @NisargShah Still the same error. I updated original post with error from dev console

Comment: are you sure that the content of the picture is for `main.html` which is in your `browsered` directory?

Comment: @pooyan 100% sure. I can even provide a screenshot if you want

Comment: Instead of screenshot try to right click on the open tab and press 'reveal in explorer` so that you can make sure about it. and also in the picture there is a brown circle on your `browsered` which can mean that there is some problem in your directory.

Comment: @pooyan Tamas Szoke's answer fixed it. By the way, the circle means git detected changes not commited in this directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with your server.

**If you use express:**

> To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files,
>   use the express.static built-in middleware function in Express.

1. Make a folder callled `public` in the root.
2. Set it in your server: `app.use(express.static('public'));`
3. Put in the files you need eg.: `some.js`.

Now you can call it with `<script src="/some.js"></script>`

[More information](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)